# JSzip file working on local host but not working on ISS server

Tags: angular, typescript, iis, server, jszip

im using jszip & jszipfile-utils for zip multiple file download (file can be any type). i was getting cors error so i have added proxy.conf.json. after adding this zip functionality is working properly on my localhost. then i hosted this angular project on IIS server also added web.config. but zip file got corrupted. when it downloaded, the file inside the zip is showing the wrong size also not opening.

for solving this i have also added allow cors origin on web.config but it doesnt work & not solved my issue.

```
let count = 0;
const zip = new JSZip();

var elements = <HTMLInputElement[]>(
  (<any>document.getElementsByName('checkbox'))
);
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
    if (elements[i].checked) {
      var getjJob = <HTMLInputElement[]>(
        (<any>document.getElementsByName('downloadMultipleFile'))
      );

      for (let j = 0; j < getjJob.length; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
          this.urlList.push(
            getjJob[j]
              .getAttribute('href')
              .replace('http://......', '')
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(this.urlList);
let urls = [];
urls = this.urlList;
if (this.urlList == '') {
  alert('Please select files..');
}
urls.forEach((url) => {
  const filename = url.toString().split('/')[
    url.toString().split('/').length - 1
  ];

  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    zip.file(filename, data, { binary: true });
    count++;

    if (count === urls.length) {
      zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then((content) => {
        const objectUrl: string = URL.createObjectURL(content);
        const link: any = document.createElement('a');

        link.download = 'zipfiles.zip';
        link.href = objectUrl;
        link.click();
      });
    }
  });
});
}
```

i want to work it fine on iis server also

Answer (score 0):

Please check to see that the .zip extension is mapped to an appropriate handler.

In the IIS, right click your website, select properties and choose to edit mime type, then check to see that mapped to something like `application/x-zip-compressed`.

Comment: application/x-zip-compressed is already mapped. on server zip file is getting downloaded but the issue is, files inside this gives wrong file size and wrong package size. this occurs corrupts files.

Comment: What does file corruption refer to? Is its size 0kb? You can check the event viewer for more detailed information.